# Optaplanner 6.4.0 webexample vehicle routing rest service not found error

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, optaplanner

We have just started experimenting with Optaplanner and are trying to run the vehicle routing webexamples in OptaPlanner 6.4.0-SNAPSHOT.

When the leaflet.jsp loads we are seeing "Error Not found" js popup. On closer examination it seems wildfly is returning

404 Not found error for.

GET /rest/vehiclerouting/solution

and 
405 (Method Not Allowed) for
POST /rest/vehiclerouting/solution/solve

(seems to be triggered by loadsolution ajax function in leaflet.jsp) 
using wildfly-servlet-10.0.0.Beta1 in standalone mode (very new to wildfly also).
(OS windows 7)

Same error is seen in 6.3 also.

Any inputs to address this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

### Prasad

Adding the code snippet from leaftlet.jsp
(As is from 6.4.0 snapshot)

```
loadSolution = function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "<%=application.getContextPath()%>/rest/vehiclerouting/solution",
  type: "GET",
  dataType : "json",
  success: function(solution) {
    var markers = [];
    $.each(solution.customerList, function(index, customer) {
      var customerIcon = L.divIcon({
        iconSize: new L.Point(20, 20),
        className: "vehicleRoutingCustomerMarker",
        html: "<span>" + customer.demand + "</span>"
      });
      var marker = L.marker([customer.latitude, customer.longitude], {icon: customerIcon});
      marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(customer.locationName + "</br>Deliver " + customer.demand + " items.");
      markers.push(marker);
    });
    map.fitBounds(L.featureGroup(markers).getBounds());
  }, error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)}
});
```

};

From github :

[VehicleRoutingRestService.java](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-webexamples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/webexamples/vehiclerouting/rest/service/VehicleRoutingRestService.java)

[web.xml](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-webexamples/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)

Comment: Edited the question with the code snippet

Comment: Did you deploy on EAP  6.4 or  WildFly 8.1+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest api requires an app server that supports JAX-RS, for example JBoss EAP 6.4 or WildFly 8.1.

For Tomcat etc, JAX-RS must be specifically added (RESTEasy for example) somehow.

Comment: My bad, was running on "Servlet-Only Distribution" 10.0.0.Beta1 so it was giving the error. Installed and ran on "Application Server Distribution" 10.0.0.Beta1, works fine now :). Thanks you @Geoffrey